# How to distinguish between null and empty string when retrieving from a bash map

Tags: bash, testing, dictionary, null, string

I am having trouble finding out how to check for null (or unset?) within a bash map.
That is, I want to treat the empty string I can place in a map differently from the case where I have placed nothing at all in the map (for that particular key).

for example, looking at the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A UsersRestrictions
UsersRestrictions['root']=""


if [[ -z "${UsersRestrictions['root']}" ]] ; then
    echo root null
else 
    echo root not null
fi

if [[ -z "${UsersRestrictions['notset']}" ]]; then
    echo notset null
else 
    echo notset not null
fi
```

I would hope the test for "root" give me 'not null' and the test for "notset" give me 'null'. But I get the same result in both cases. I have searched for other possible methods, but all give me the same results so far. Is there a way to achieve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `-z ${parameter:+word}` as your test condition. It will always be true if parameter is null or unset, otherwise it will be false.

From the bash man page:

> **${parameter:+word}**
>
> Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is
>   substituted.

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A UsersRestrictions
UsersRestrictions['root']=""
UsersRestrictions['foo']="bar"
UsersRestrictions['spaces']="    "

for i in root foo spaces notset
do
    if [[ -z "${UsersRestrictions[$i]+x}" ]]; then
        echo "$i is null"
    else 
        echo "$i is not null. Has value: [${UsersRestrictions[$i]}]"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
root is not null. Has value: []
foo is not null. Has value: [bar]
spaces is not null. Has value: [    ]
notset is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if [[ -z "${UsersRestrictions['notset']}" && "${UsersRestrictions['notset']+x}" ]]; then
    echo "notset is defined (can be empty)"
else 
    echo "notset is not defined at all"
fi
```

The trick is to concatenate a dummy `x` character, which will only be appended when the variable *is* defined (whether it's empty or not). Also note that the first test for `root` is supposed to give you `root null`, since the value is effectively empty. If you want to test if the value is *not* empty, use `if [[ ! -z $var ]]` instead.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/sMtPG)**.

#### References:

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Other Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: `-n` appears to treats empty strings as null as well. Try: `test ! -n "" && echo true`